# Accessing usercontrols in code-behind in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

This question is for an ASP.NET guru. Its driving me nuts.

I have inherited an ASP.NET Web Forms application. This application uses a complex 
structure of nested user controls. While complex, it does seem necessary in this case. 
Regardless, I have a page that uses a single UserControl. We will call this UserControl 
root control. This UserControl is defined as follows:

**widget.ascx**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="widget.ascx.cs" Inherits="resources_userControls_widget" %>
<div>
  <asp:Panel ID="bodyPanel" runat="server" />
</div>
```

**widget.ascx.cs**

```
public partial class resources_userControls_widget : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    private string source = string.Empty;
    public string Source
    {
        get { return source; }
        set { source = value; }
    }

    private string parameter1 = string.Empty;
    public string Parameter1
    {
        get { return parameter1; }
        set { parameter1 = value; }
    }

    private DataTable records = new DataTable();
    public DataTable Records
    {
        get { return records; }
        set { records = value; }
    }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);
        UserControl userControl = LoadControl(source) as UserControl;
        if (parameter1.Length > 0)
            userControl.Attributes.Add("parameter1", parameter1);
        bodyPanel.Controls.Add(userControl);
    }

    private void InsertUserControl(string filename)
    {
    }
}
```

In my application, I am using widget.ascx in the following way:
**page.aspx**

```
<uc:Widget ID="myWidget" runat="server"  Source="/userControls/widgets/info.ascx" />
```

**page.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  DataTable table = GetData();
  myWidget.Records = table;
}
```

Please notice how info.ascx is set as the UserControl we want to load in this case. This approach is necessary in this case. I've removed the extraneous code that justifies it to focus on the problem. Regardless, in info.ascx.cs I have the following:

**info.ascx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Here's the problem
  // this.Parent.Parent is a widget.ascx instance.
  // However, I cannot access the Widget class. I want to be able to do this
  // Widget widget = (Widget)(this.Parent.Parent);
  // DataTable table = widget.Records;
}
```

I really need to get the value of the "Records" property from the Parent user control. Unfortunately, I can't seem to access the Widget class from my code-behind. Are there some rules about UserControl visibility at compile time that I'm not aware of? How do I access the Widget class from the code-behind of info.ascx.cs?

Thank you!

Comment: Just curious, what does this.Parent.Parent.ToString() report to be?

Comment: Parent.Parent.ToString() shows the name of the class I'm trying to get (Widget). That's what is so odd about all of this. At runtime, I can see the class name just fine. However, during dev / compile-time, Widget is not available in IntelliSense. If I just use it, disregarding IntelliSense, compilation fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you need to create an interface and implement it to the Widget user control class.

For instance,

```
public interface IRecord
{
    DataTable Records {get;set;}
} 

public partial class resources_userControls_widget : System.Web.UI.UserControl, IRecord
{
 ...
}
```

And in code behind of Info.ascx.cs,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Here's the problem
  // this.Parent.Parent is a widget.ascx instance.
  // However, I cannot access the Widget class. I want to be able to do this
  // Widget widget = (Widget)(this.Parent.Parent);
  // DataTable table = widget.Records;

  IRecord record=this.Parent.Parent;
  DataTable table = widget.Records;
}
```

Comment: Very slick. I'll give it a shot and if it works, I'll credit this post. But I like this idea.

Comment: Sorry, guys, but IRecord record=this.Parent.Parent; - it's a stupid, because Parent has a Control type and cannot implement any custom interface.

Comment: @ Phone Developer - I was wrong - it work up to time you change you control hierarchy. If you add MasterPage or change existent control hierarchy you will get runtime error. But its up to you.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, maybe better to use some server object's like ViewState or Session. Fill it within DataTable on your page and get it in Page_load event handler on info.ascx user control.